# Graphics Card or Monitor is failing

Tags: graphics-card, display

Every few minutes my monitor will go black for about 2 seconds. I can't find a pattern regarding what is on the screen, though it seems to happen more often in video games.

How can I tell if the video card is faulty or the monitor itself is faulty? Or possibly a third variable?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to borrow another monitor and test it out.  If that fixes the issue than you know it was the monitor otherwise a video card is a possibility.   Some other things to check:

- The monitor cable.  Maybe a short somewhere.
- Is the computer staying cool enough? (Are vents possibly blocked?)

Answer (score 2):

the first thing- update your video drivers.if the problem is only with in the games then check your graphics card and system temp with gpu-z and cpu-z softwares.

if the problem is not with system temp then this could be a software conflict also. i think this is not a monitor problem you can check your monitor on a different system.